# Finding number of pythagorean triples in a list using python?

Tags: python, computer-science, pythagorean

I am coding a solution for a problem where the code will find the number of Pythagorean triples in a list given a list a. However, when I submit my code to the auto-grader, there are some test cases where my code fails, but I have no idea what went wrong. Please help me point out my mistake.....

```
def Q3(a):
    lst = [i ** 2 for i in a]
    lst.sort()
    ans = 0

    for x in lst:
        for y in lst:
            if (x + y) in lst:
                ans += 1

    return ans // 2
```

"Pythagorean triples" are integer solutions to the Pythagorean Theorem, for example, 32+42=52. Given a list of positive integers, find the number of Pythagorean triplets. Two Pythagorean triplets are different if at least one integer is different.

Implementation

·        Implement a function Q3(A), where the A is a list of positive integers. The size of list A is up to 250.

·        There are no duplicates in the list A

·        This function returns the number of Pythagorean triplets.

Sample

·        Q3( [3,4,6,5] ) = 1

·        Q3( [4,5,6] ) = 0

Comment: How many Pythogorean triples are in `[3,4,5,5,5]`? How many would your function say there are?

Comment: your iterating over the same range so x and y could both be the same element

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution that should pass the test cases provided that they're performance-related.

Answer (score 1):

Simple but not very efficient solution would be to loop through the list of numbers in the range (I have taken number from 1 to 100 for instance) in 3 nested for loops as below. But it would be slower as for 100 elements, it needs to have 100^3 operations

```
triplets = []
for base in range(1,101):
    for height in range(1,101):
        for hypotenuse in range(1,101):
            # check if forms a triplet

            if hypotenuse**2 == base**2 + height**2:
                triplets.append(base, height, hypotenuse)
```

This can be made slightly more efficient (there are better solutions)
by calculating hypotenuse for each base and height combination and then check if the hypotenuse is an Integer

```
    triplets = []
    for base in range(1,101):
        for height in range(1,101):
            hypotenuse = math.sqrt(base**2 + height**2)
            # check if hypotenuse is integer by ramiander division by 1                    
            if hypotenuse%1==0:
                triplets.append(base, height, hypotenuse)  
                 

# the above solution written a list comprehension
a = range(1,101)
[(i,j,math.sqrt(i*i+j*j)) for i in a for j in a if math.sqrt(i*i+j*j)%1==0]
```

If you consider (3,4,5) and (3,5,4) as different, use a set instead of list and get the len(triplets_set) in the end

Answer (score -1):

Problem 1: Suppose your input is

```
[3,4,5,5,5]
```

Though it's somewhat unclear in your question, my presumption is that this should count as three Pythogorean triples, each using one of the three 5s.

Your function would only return 1.

Problem 2: As Sayse points out, your "triple" might be trying to use the same number twice.

You would be better off using `itertools.combinations` to get distinct combinations from your squares list, and counting how many suitable triples appear.

```
from itertools import combinations

def Q3(a):
    squares = [i**2 for i in a]
    squares.sort()
    ans = 0

    for x,y,z in combinations(squares, 3):
        if x + y == z:
            ans += 1

    return ans
```

Answer (score -1):

Given the constraints of the input you now added to your question with an edit, I don't think there's anything logically wrong with your implementation. The only type of test cases that your code can fail to pass has to be performance-related as you are using one of the slowest solutions by using 3 nested loops iterating over the full range of the list (the `in` operator itself is implemented with a loop).

Since the list is sorted and we want `x < y < z`, we should make `y` start from `x + 1` and make `z` start from `y + 1`. And since given an `x`, the value of `x` depends on the value of `y`, for each given `y` we can increment `z` until `z * z < x * x + y * y` no longer holds, and if `z * z == x * x + y * y` at that point, we've found a Pythagorean triple. This allows `y` and `z` to sweep through the values above `x` only once and therefore reduces the time complexity from O(n^3) to O(n^2), making it around 40 times faster when the size of the list is 250:

```
def Q3(a):
    lst = [i * i for i in sorted(a)]
    ans = 0
    for x in range(len(lst) - 2):
        y = x + 1
        z = y + 1
        while z < len(lst):
            while z < len(lst) and lst[z] < lst[x] + lst[y]:
                z += 1
            if z < len(lst) and lst[z] == lst[x] + lst[y]:
                ans += 1
            y += 1
    return ans
```